# Get current position Google Maps api from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, google-api

I have a javascript to take my current position and draw it in Google Maps, but I would like to have,also, the coordinates in variable usable in PHP . 
I have :

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(mostra_mappa);
}else{
alert('La geo-localizzazione NON è possibile');
}

function mostra_mappa(position) {
var punto = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.lat, position.coords.long),

opzioni = {
zoom: 15,
center: punto,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
},
contenitore = document.getElementById("mia_mappa"),
mappa = new google.maps.Map(contenitore, opzioni),
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: punto,
map: mappa,
title: "Tu sei qui!"
});
}
</script>
```

Now, I would like to take the coordinates x and y (previous computed) of my position and put its into the request(as follow) :

```
$x =?????;
$y=??????;
$String = file_get_contents('http://api.yelp.com/business_review_searchterm=restaurant&lat=' . $x.'&long='. $y . '&radius=20&limit=500&ywsid=uHhsYI82_aEk8Q9NjSsIzg');
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send your coordinates to the PHP file. Javascript...

```
var data = { 
    'x': position.coords.lat,
    'y': position.coords.lon
};

$.post('script.php', { coordinates: JSON.stringify(data) }, function () {
    // deal with your returned Yelp review...
});
```

PHP...

```
if (isset($_POST['coordinates'])) {
    $geo = json_decode($_POST['coordinates']);

    $x = $geo.x;
    $y= $geo.y;

    // get Yelp review here
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement you suggestion, but I failed. The thing is that is possible to pass the javascript variables to Php.

Comment: @user3043636, see the edited answer and try it that way, with `JSON.stringify()`. This should make sure that your Javascript objects are correctly parsed as a JSON string.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand where i must put your suggest javascript code and Php code. I'm new in this kind of languages, could you,please, explain better. thanks

Comment: Put the Javascript at the end of your existing code. The PHP code would go in the beginning of your script.